# How to only iterate through certain rows in a DataFrame using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created DataFrames for 'Case' and 'X_Value' below.

Now I am trying iterate through 'Case' and write each 'X_Value' to a text file for each specific Case.  For example, I want to write all of the X_Values for Case 1 to a file (0.5, 1.2, 5.6) and all X_Values to a file for Case 2 (6.3, 9.5, 11.3).  Please help!  I have tried iterrows, grouping, etc. and nothing gives me the result I am looking for.

```
Case     X_Value  
1        0.5  
1        1.2  
1        5.6  
2        6.3  
2        9.5  
2        11.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to achieve something like below?

```
from pandas import DataFrame


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'1': [0.5, 1.2, 5.6],
            '2': [6.3, 9.5, 11.3]}
    df = DataFrame(data)

    print(df)

    for i in data.keys():
        file = "Case{}.txt".format(i)
        case = open(file, mode="w+")
        case.writelines(str(df[str(i)]))
        case.close()
```

Output is:

```
     1     2
0  0.5   6.3
1  1.2   9.5
2  5.6  11.3
```

Case1.txt:

```
0    0.5
1    1.2
2    5.6
```

Case2.txt

```
0     6.3
1     9.5
2    11.3
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I am looking for!  The only thing is that I am not sure how to convert my data into a dictionary.  I cannot hard code it because I have 1000+ cases which would be the "keys" and 10 X_Values for each Case which would be the "values" in a list format.  If you have any insight as to how to do this, it would be very much appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: What is your current data type? is it `list` or `numoy` array? or something else?

Comment: The data is currently being stored in a spreadsheet so that is part of the battle is figuring out the best data type to read it in as. I was trying to work with lists but couldn't get my desired outcome that way.